# Conditional list comprehension with 2 lists

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Is it possible to convert this yield-function into a (more concise) list comprehension?

```
l1 = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'sum', 'sum', 'sum']
l2 = ['', '', '', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3']

def getList(l1, l2):
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        yield l2[i] if l1[i] == 'sum' else l1[i]

print(list(getList(l1, l2)))
```

Thx & kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can write the loop as a list comprehension like so:

```
def getList(l1, l2)
    return [b if b == 'sum' else a for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Note that the function is no longer a generator, since it does not yield single values but returns a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
list_comp = [i for i in (l1+l2) if i not in ['', 'sum']]

print(list_comp)
#['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `map()` for this:

```
def get_list(l1, l2):
    return list(map(lambda x, y: y if y == 'sum' else x, l1, l2))
```